# Update custom field from Identity user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

Hey I try to persist updated fields from my Identity User like this:

```
 var storage = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new SpomunicateContext());
 var manager = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager<ApplicationUser>(storage);
 await manager.UpdateAsync(user);
```

This doesnt work because I get this error:

> "Attaching an entity of type 'SpommunicateWebAPI.Models.ApplicationUser' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.",

And I have no idea what happend..  There is no entity like Application User.
I only got this class:

```
   public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here

        return userIdentity;
    }


    public virtual ICollection<Function> Functions { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Participation> Participations { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Team> Teams { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }
}
```

}

could that be the problem?
Before owin I got a Entity Person with the same fields but I dropped my Db and removed the entity so I think that could not be the problem.

**EDIT**
I get my user from here:

```
public static ApplicationUser GetUserByUsername(string username)
    {
            return HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().FindByNameAsync(username).Result;
    }
```

Comment: The ApplicationUser class is your entity, it inherits from IdentityUser. Both map default to the AspNetUsers table. I see you have a user to update, but can you show where you get user?

Comment: added it to the question..